# Buttons get elongated

Tags: html, css

[image: Red background]

Can someone please why this keeps happening? 
With buttons I usually fix it by adding align-items: center or text-align center, but in this case doesn't work .
Ill leave you the code below and also the github if you want to see all the code. Please ignore the text is a dummy text.
github:  https://github.com/CodyHiII/My-Portfolio-Site

here is the code

```
.portfolio__card {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.portfolio__text i{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: flex;  
    justify-content: center;
    transition: transform 100ms ease-in;
    background-color: red;
}
.portfolio__text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0071bc;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `background-color: red;`?  Also your example works fine in chrome

Comment: I deleted my old answer because the question was unclear. The link is the full width because it is 100% of your parent div `class="coder portfolio__card"` which in the code is 400px width. If you want your background color to change on hover do something like `a:hover i.icon { color: red; }`

Comment: I don't want the bg color to change. The hover effect is triggered when the cursor hits the background too ,I want the hover to be triggered only when it hits the icon that is visible . The red bg is only for you too see the area in questions.

Comment: Setting `display:flex` stretches element to fit parent container. Your element `i` does not have content so setting `justify-content: center;` makes no sense. You would need to set in on wrapper or center it other way.

Comment: how could I center them ?